# Implement 'Add to Home Screen' in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to know how to implement like pic. I want to put the function like Add automatically on my app.
Do you have any ideas? 
I need the sample codes.

V/r,

[image]

Comment: It is pretty unclear what you are asking. Do you need help to build this layout in Flutter? Is your Flutter app indeed a PWA web-app and you want this functionality? If any of the above, please show us what you *can* do so far, what your next step is and what *specific* problems you have with it.

Comment: I would like to know how to implement like pic.
I want to put the function like Add automatically on my app.